# Finding minimum number of required 'central points'

Tags: algorithm, graph, cluster-analysis

I have a set of 'n' nodes. A function returns a kind of distance between two nodes such that dist(a,c) may not be dist(a,b)+dist(b,c). Based on a threshold I connect certain nodes via edges. I wish to select the minimum number of nodes such that the set of these nodes and their immediate edge connected neighbours comprise the whole set of n nodes. Is an optimum solution possible? Scribbling on paper made me think centrality can help (degree,closeness?). Clustering occurred to me but the nodes in this graph don't have attributes. How do I select the min number of nodes? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wish to select the minimum number of nodes such that the set of
>   these nodes and their immediate edge connected neighbours comprise the
>   whole set of n nodes

This is [Dominating Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set).

Since we can easily define `d(u,v) = 1` for all nodes where (u,v) is an edge, we can easily reduce Vertex Cover to your problem.

Since Dominating-Set is [NP-Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness), and the above is a polynomial reduction, so is your problem.

**tl;dr:** Your problem is NP-Complete and there is no known efficient solution to solve it optimally.

Comment: This is actually Dominating Set, not Vertex Cover.  It's related, but harder in some ways (e.g. it's not fixed-parameter tractable).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Cheers. I am always confusing between the two. Thanks for noticing. fixed.